# Malware? Or a Browser Hijack by Google?

Tags: browser-hijacking

Today, clicking on links (via Chrome from my Google home page), I started seeing "https://beinternetawesome.withgoogle.com/en_us/" come up instead of the site I had attempted to load.

I'm trying to determine if this is due to typical/traditional malware, or a bug at Google, or simply an inappropriate decision by Google that appears to meet the definition of a browser hijack.

I have found one other reference to it, at: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/76979340?hl=en

Other than that, I've been unable to find info on the unrequested redirect part of this, though I have confirmed that the site being loaded without consent is a valid Google site. Is any further info on this public yet?

Thanks in advance for any further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved (I believe). This appears to be a bug in the "New Tab Page" for Google Chrome when a user is signed in. There are a lot of variables here, so it is possible this only happens under specific settings.

At the bottom of this home page, there is an invisible link to what appears to be Google's choice of positive messaging. However, during page load, this link can end up positioned over top of the automatically generated shortcut buttons.

Screenshot below (my cursor wasn't captured, so notes added in red text.)

[image]

I believe I was just clicking on links like Facebook before the page had finished rendering, so this invisible link was the active element under my cursor at the time of the click.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, this is pretty bizarre. This is what I found.

[beinternetawesome FAQ](https://beinternetawesome.withgoogle.com/en_us/faq)

It sounds like you have *Parental Controls* set.

[Parental Controls](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/510?hl=en&ref_topic=3425457#)

How SafeSearch works

When SafeSearch is on, it helps filter out explicit content in Google's search results for all your queries across images, videos, and websites. While SafeSearch isn’t 100% accurate, it’s designed to help block explicit results, like pornography, from your Google search results. Learn more about how to stay safe online at safety.google.

When SafeSearch is off, we'll provide the most relevant results for your search which may include explicit content when you search for it.

> SafeSearch can be turned on for:
>
> ```
> Personal accounts or browsers
> Children’s supervised devices and accounts using the Family Link app
> Workplace or school devices and networks
> ```

> Turn SafeSearch on or off
>
> ```
> Go to Search Settings.
> Under "SafeSearch filters," check or uncheck the box next to "Turn on SafeSearch."
> At the bottom of the page, select Save.
> ```
>
> Change your child’s SafeSearch settings in the Family Link app
>
> The SafeSearch setting is on by default for signed-in users under 13
> (or applicable age in your country), managed with Family Link. Only
> parents can turn the SafeSearch setting off. Learn more about Search &
> your child’s Google Account with the Family Link app.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and confirmed that safe search was (and is) off. Also, I found that the redirect stopped happening after a while (possibly it was once per link). Then the links started working normally. This has not happened since, though I did get it to start again by forcing Chrome to quit and launching it again. So it looks like either a weird bug, or possibly a bad decision related to advertising that site. (Probably a bug.)